# Combining Multiple row values in a single line SSRS expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

There are three rows in my SQL output which I would like to view them in a single line when I want to view them while running the SSRS report.

Source Data

[image]

These two columns are part of my DataSet1 in the SSRS report.

Output I am expecting in the SSRS report (Expression): ***Semester 1 2017, Semester 2 2017, Semester 3 2017***

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could use `STUFF()` function with `xml path` method for that

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Semester = STUFF(
                       (
                           SELECT ','+CONCAT(Semester, ' ', [year])
                           FROM <table> FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, '')
FROM <table>;
```

**Update :** You could use `CONCAT()` function for combining the `year` & `Semester`

Result :

```
Semester
Semester 1 2017,Semester 2 2017,Semester 3 2017
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh. I just realised that I missed the year in my output. And how do I show this in the SSRS expression?

Comment: I have updated the dataset and it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql

```
SELECT STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + Semesters 
              FROM table t1
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') AS Semesters from table t2
```